# Given an input generate all combinations where each digit is one bigger or one smaller

Tags: python, algorithm, math, combinatorics

So for example given 123456, no digits can be unchanged but each will either go up one or down one for example 234567 or 012345 or 212565. I believe there should be 2^N combinations, where N is the number of digits.

I have no idea where to start. I was thinking for loops but I can't think of a systematic way to run through every combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in your approach of using a systematic method to generate all combinations where each digit in a given number is either increased or decreased by one. For a number with N digits, there indeed are
2^N such combinations. This is because for each digit, you have two choices: either increase it by one or decrease it by one.
The function generates all combinations for a given number where each digit is either increased or decreased by one. For the example "123456", it successfully creates 64 combinations, as expected for a 6-digit number (2^6=64). The function works for any number of digits and provides a set of strings representing all possible combinations according to your criteria.

```
 def generate_combinations(number_str):
    if not number_str:
        return {''}  # Base case: return a set with an empty string
    smaller_combinations = generate_combinations(number_str[1:])
    digit = int(number_str[0])
    new_combinations = set()
    for combo in smaller_combinations:
        if digit < 9:
            new_combinations.add(str(digit + 1) + combo)
        if digit > 0:
            new_combinations.add(str(digit - 1) + combo)
    return new_combinations

  test_number = "123456"
  combinations = generate_combinations(test_number)
  print(len(combinations), combinations)
```

**Output** :            64 {'234367', '032547', '014545', '214545', '232545', '014567', '034567', '214547', '212345', '212567', '014365', '012347', '214347', '032345', '232347', '034367', '234545', '034347', '014347', '012367', '214345', '234365', '012545', '032365', '032347', '234567', '212545', '232565', '212347', '214565', '214567', '014547', '012345', '214367', '014565', '232367', '034365', '232345', '034565', '032565', '034545', '232567', '234345', '232365', '234565', '212565', '032545', '234347', '012547', '012365', '012567', '214365', '212547', '014367', '032567', '232547', '212365', '034345', '034547', '234547', '014345', '212367', '012565', '032367'}

Changing to accommodate 0 and 9

```
def generate_combinations(number_str):
    if not number_str:
        return {''}  # Base case: return a set with an empty string
    smaller_combinations = generate_combinations(number_str[1:])
    digit = int(number_str[0])
    new_combinations = set()
    for combo in smaller_combinations:
        if digit < 9:
            new_combinations.add(str(digit + 1) + combo)
        if digit > 0:
            new_combinations.add(str(digit - 1) + combo)
        if digit == 0:
            new_combinations.add(str(9) + combo)
        if digit == 9:
            new_combinations.add(str(0) + combo)
    return new_combinations

test_number = "0123496"
combinations = generate_combinations(test_number)
print(len(combinations), combinations)
```

**Output**:
128 {'9234585', '9232587', '9212305', '1212307', '1212385', '1212585', '9232307', '1012305', '1032587', '1214387', '9234387', '1012505', '1234505', '1014307', '1032585', '1012307', '1212305', '9012505', '1232305', '9014585', '9214505', '1032505', '1012585', '9012587', '9032385', '9012305', '1234307', '9034387', '9014305', '1034585', '9032585', '1234507', '1232585', '9014505', '1034505', '9034587', '1214307', '9034385', '1032387', '9012585', '9032505', '1012387', '9214385', '1212505', '1234387', '1232307', '1214505', '1234585', '9212385', '9014307', '1034385', '1212587', '1032385', '9232385', '1034587', '1234587', '1034305', '9234307', '9232505', '1234385', '9014507', '9014385', '9212587', '1214587', '9234507', '1014387', '9032307', '9014387', '1014505', '1034507', '9212387', '9034585', '9232387', '1014305', '1032305', '1014385', '9012307', '9232305', '9212307', '1232387', '1212387', '1214507', '1232385', '1232587', '9214587', '9234587', '9212585', '9034507', '1034387', '9034305', '9012387', '1014507', '9214387', '9032587', '1014585', '9214585', '9214507', '9212507', '1214305', '9014587', '1212507', '1214385', '9214305', '1032507', '9234505', '9214307', '9032507', '9032387', '9234305', '1034307', '9012507', '1032307', '9232507', '9232585', '1012587', '1232507', '9034505', '1014587', '1214585', '9012385', '1232505', '9034307', '1012507', '9234385', '1012385', '9032305', '9212505', '1234305'}

Comment: This is very helpful as I can see the logic. I think it however breaks down if any digits are 0 or 9. I can make the adjustments to fix this.

Comment: I don't think it will break for "0123496" answer is 32 which is correct

Comment: there should be 2^n combinations but it basically doesn't count any digit which has 0,9 so we end up with 2^5 which is 32 instead of 128 for 7 digits.

Comment: yes that is true but it is as per the rules defined by you. Ahh got the point good sir. Yes a minor tweak can take care of it. Do you want me to do that?

Comment: Yes please, I am still a little confused.

Comment: There will not generally be `2^n` answers. There will be `2^m` where `m` is the number of digits that are not `0` or `9`. In the case of `123456`, `m` will be `n`. But, for instance, `5000` will only produce 2 outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Let `num` be the string representation of a non-negative number.

We can obtain all desired combinations by mapping each number between zero and 2<sup>n</sup>-1 to one of the combinations, where `n` equals the number of characters in `num` that are between `'1'` and `'8'`. For each of the 2<sup>n</sup> numbers to be mapped we examine its binary representation. If a digit equals `0` (`1`) the associated character in `num` (if it is between `'1'` and `'8'`) is decreased (increased) by one.

I will present the code in Ruby, which can be read as pseudo-code. I will give examples that should make the calculations clear. Translating the code to Python should be straightforward.

---

First, define two hashes ("dictionaries" in Python) as constants.

```
UP = ('0'..'8').zip('1'..'9').to_h
  #=> {"0"=>"1", "1"=>"2", "2"=>"3", "3"=>"4", "4"=>"5", "5"=>"6",
  #    "6"=>"7", "7"=>"8", "8"=>"9"}

DN = UP.invert
  #=> {"1"=>"0", "2"=>"1", "3"=>"2", "4"=>"3", "5"=>"4", "6"=>"5",
  #    "7"=>"6", "8"=>"7", "9"=>"8"}
```

Then, for example,

```
UP["2"] #=> "3"
DN["3"] #=> "2"
```

---

Next create a method that will return an array of digits from the binary representation of a non-negative number `n`.

```
def binary_digits(n)
  n.bit_length.times.map { |d| n[d] }
end
```

For example,

```
binary_digits(3)
  #=> [1, 1]
binary_digits(13)
  #=> [1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Leading zeroes are generated as needed, as will be explained below, when the method `one_combo` is discussed.

---

The main method is the following.

```
def combos(num)
  sz = num.each_char.count { |c| ('1'..'9').cover?(c) }
  (2**sz).times.map { |n| one_combo(num, n) }
end
```

Suppose, for example,

```
num = '073492'
```

Then `sz` will equal `4` (the number of characters in `num` between `1` and `8`). There will therefore be 2<sup>4</sup> = 16 combinations derived from `num`, each defined by method `one_combo`, which I turn to now.

---

```
def one_combo(num, n)
  bds = binary_digits(n)
  num.each_char.with_object('') do |c,s|
    s <<
    case c
    when '0'
      '1'
    when '9'
      '8'
    else
      bds.shift.to_i.zero? ? DN[c] : UP[c]
    end
  end
end
```

Suppose, as before, `num = '073492'` and the method is called with `n = 6`:

```
one_combo('073492', 6)     
  #=> "164581"
```

The first calculation is:

```
bds = binary_digits(6)
  #=> [0, 1, 1]
```

The loop builds and returns a string `s`. The steps are are as follows:

- `'0'` of `num` is increased to `'1'`, the only choice;
- `'7'` of `num` is reduced to `'6'` because the first element of `bds` equals `0` and `bds` is shortened to `[1, 1]`;
- `'3'` of `num` is increased to `'4'` because the first element of `bds` equals `1` and `bds` is shortened to `[1]`;
- `'4'` of `num` is increased to `'5'` because the first element of `bds` equals `1` and `bds` is shortened to `[]`;
- `'9'` of `num` is reduced to `'8'`, the only choice; and
- `'2'` of `num` is reduced to `'1'` because the `bds` is empty, in which case `[].first` returns `nil` and `nil` is converted to zero.

---

We can now generate the `16` combinations for `num = '073492'`:

```
combos('073492')
  #=> ["162381", "182381", "164381", "184381", "162581", "182581",
  #    "164581", "184581", "162383", "182383", "164383", "184383",
  #    "162583", "182583", "164583", "184583"]
```